# React Router location key undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In the current app Im working on I have set up the router (react-router-dom v5 / react 17) to point basically have two separate views, the login and the / meaning the rest of them (inherits some layout things), looking like the following:

```
 <Switch>
  {/*Login Route*/}
  <Route path="/login">
    <LoginPage />
  </Route>

  <Route path='/'>
    <PrimaryLayout>
       <Switch>
          <Route path={`/overview`}>
             <OverviewPage />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/" exact>
             <HomePage />
          </Route>

          <Route path="*" exact>
             NOT FOUND!
           </Route>

       </Switch>
    </PrimaryLayout>
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

While this works, I'm having a issue with `location.key` from `useLocation()` hook, where it works for the above structure, but comes back undefined for nested routes within, for example, `OverviewPage`

```
Some content in the Overview Page etc...
.....
<Route>
  <Switch>
      <Route path={`${path}/:parentId`}>
           testingLocationKey {location.key}
      </Route>

      <Route path='*'>
           <Redirect to={path}/>
      </Route>
  </Switch>
</Route>
```

Not sure if this structure is correct, but it does match the above location, in the nested routes in the Overview page, however the location.key is undefined when it does. (needed for route transitions). Any tips or help is much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if it will help you, but from what i read [here](https://dev.to/raaynaldo/react-router-usehistory-uselocation-and-useparams-10cd), the `key` from `useLocation` is not always define

Comment: Wierd part is that I have tried passing it down as prop from component to component, but still comes back as undefined